# Ionization trends in period 6

Tags: ionization-energy

I know that there is a drop of Ionization energy in the second period with Nitrogen and Oxygen, but why does that not apply to bismiuth and polonium, which are in the same groups but different period.

Comment: Trends are, well, just trends. Basically all such ‘rules’ of things up/down/sideways/across the periodic table have problems somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bi and Po have 6 shells however Nitrogen and Oxygen have 2 shells...
Due to bigger radius of bismuth and polonium there is no significant drop in the enthalpy.
Plus they both have almost similar mass number(difference of just 0.002)